# Can Nexus card be used at US airports if arriving from country other than Canada?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, global-entry, nexus, trusted-traveler

If you have a Nexus membership (and NOT Global Entry), have you used your card at the Global Entry kiosk at an US airport to get the Global Entry benefits?

Nexus can clearly be used at participating Canadian Preclearance airports to enter the US and you get the Global Entry Benefits.

A lot of people say that Nexus is superior to Global Entry program and they point out the following facts.
1. Nexus is cheaper ($50 as opposed to Global Entry which costs $100)
2. Nexus gets you into the fast lane when entering Canada from USA by air/water/land. Global Entry does not give you that benefit.
3. Nexus gets you into fast lane when entering Mexico from USA (because of the reciprocal benefits between Nexus and Sentri program). Global Entry does not give you that benefit.
4. *"using Global Entry kioks when entering the United States.."*

Reference: [Benefits of NEXUS](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/benefits-nexus)

I am having trouble understanding the item number 4 above. Does Nexus give you the "Global Entry" benefit, only if you are using the Nexus kiosks at one of the ten preclearance airports (Reference: [Airports with NEXUS Kiosks](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/airports-kiosks))?   Whatever I read suggests that Nexus card CANNOT be used with the Global Entry kiosks at the US airports, if arriving at US from any country other than Canada (say, Brazil or Japan) or from any Canadian airport other than the Pre-clearance airports.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NEXUS membership can be used at Global Entry kiosks, though the physical card is not used at preclearence airports. NEXUS "[includes Global Entry benefits](https://www.dhs.gov/trusted-traveler-comparison-chart)" (and TSA Precheck). See also this announcement from CBP: [NEXUS and SENTRI Members May Utilize the Global Entry Kiosks](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/global-entry-kiosks).

As you've noted, NEXUS includes the benefits of Global Entry at a lower cost, so you might wonder why everyone doesn't choose that option. With NEXUS, the eligibility requirements are a bit different (citizens of certain other countries are eligible for Global Entry and not NEXUS) and you have to visit a NEXUS enrollment center to apply. There are many more Global Entry enrollment centers, while the NEXUS centers are close to the US-Canada border. If your travels don't take you near a NEXUS enrollment center, Global Entry is the better choice, unless you're working a trip into a mileage run or something.

You don't actually use the physical card NEXUS card at the kiosks, except for "designated NEXUS sites" ([Preclearence airports](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/airports-kiosks), [land borders](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/land-border-crossings)) where you can use it in place of a passport. At all other Global Entry equipped US airports, you scan your passport and fingerprints at the kiosk and your membership is checked electronically. I was told that, in theory, the card is supposed to let you skip the line if all the kiosks are broken though. The card is also an additional form of federal ID, which could always come in handy.

Comment: Actually the Global Entry machines at Canadian preclearance airports will accept the physical NEXUS card in lieu of a passport, to allow the card alone to be used for Canada-US travel. NEXUS members must use their passports at GE machines in US airports no matter where they are arriving from. Green card holders must instead always use their green card at all GE machines.

Comment: Starting the answer with "yes" is kind of misleading.  The question is whether the *card* can be used, and the answer is no, it can't.

Comment: OP did not mention what passport s/he holds? Canadian/US citizens with passports can use nexus card in lieu of passport for entering US/Canada (in most cases), but citizens of other countries may not. 

Also, as a NEXUS holder having passport of third country with no green card, I am NOT eligible for TSA-precheck (only Canadian citizens, US citizens and US green card holders with NEXUS membership are).

Answer (score 3):

I received a definitive answer from CBP.  In summary, if you have NEXUS, do not apply for Global Entry.  Using the Global Entry lines with an active NEXUS enrollment will expedite you into the USA from international locations outside of North America, even at non-border airport locations lacking NEXUS signage.

E-mail received from CBP Information Center [cbpinfocenter@cbp.dhs.gov] on 2024-01-16:

> Thank you for contacting the CBP Traveler Communications Center.
>
> If you have NEXUS, you already have Global Entry benefits. If you are applying to switch to the Global Entry program from NEXUS, you will lose NEXUS benefits upon approval of Global Entry. You can only have one program membership at a time.
> Thank you again for contacting the Traveler Communications Center.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, you don't need your Global Entry or Nexus card to use the GE kiosks. You come up, it scans your face and the machine then tells you it's all clear or "go talk to an agent". If you don't talk to an agent you never once have to pull out *any* documentation whatsoever.